# MethodGroup as a generic parameter

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda

I am trying to write a method that returns a methodinfo class from a given input, with a view to creating the generic version of that method...i.e.

```
var m = myClass.GetType().GetMethod("SomeMethod").MakeGenericMethod(...blahblah..);
```

This works and is all good, except that I have the string literal of my method name, so if in the course of re-factoring I happen to rename one of the methods I am using I don't find out until run time.

What I would like to do is create a helper method that I can pass a lamba to that specifies the methodgroup, that way I would get compile time checking of the method name, not to mention intellisense etc...ie.

```
MethodInfo mi = myClass.GetMethodInfo( o => o.SomeMethod );
m = mi.MakeGenericMethod(..blah...);
```

But I haven't been able to figure out the method signature of the helper...

```
public MethodInfo GetMethodInfo(Func<MyClass,XXXX> lambda){ //What is my XXXX ? }
```

Comment: What does the signature of your `SomeMethod` look like?

Comment: actually that's the point @M.Babcock they might and probably will be different, that's why I want to resolve from the method group, not a specific method signature.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, however I could be wrong. `Func` expects to know what to pass to the lambda, if you don't know then how can it?

Comment: There really isn't that easy of a method you can make without having overload explosion, stick with the strings. Likely those methods don't change often, and you probably dono't have lots of them (or at least you shouldn't). Also, why not move from reflection calls to dynamic calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this, but I am stumped as to why you need the to specify the delegate type.  Without that it doesn't work, but since the below works for `BarMethod`, it doesn't seem to matter what the delegate type is:

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    Foo f = new Foo();
    Console.WriteLine(ForMethod(() => f.FooMethod()).Name);
    Console.WriteLine(ForMethod(() => f.Foo2Method<String>()).Name);
    Console.WriteLine(ForMethod(() => f.BarMethod("foo")).Name);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static MethodInfo ForMethod(Expression<Action> e)
{
    var mi = ((MethodCallExpression) e.Body).Method;
    if (mi.IsGenericMethod)
        mi = mi.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
    return mi;
}

class Foo
{
    public void FooMethod() { }
    public void Foo2Method<T>() { }
    public void BarMethod(String foo) { }
}
```

Comment: I thought about this also, but based on the question, the methods are likely going to be generic methods, so you will need to check if the method is generic method and get underlying method definition

Comment: Edited to cover that possibility.  For what it's worth, there almost certainly is a better way.

Comment: I made it slightly more palatable by pushing the delegate type (Action) into the ForMethod definition.  Still *quite* puzzled as to how this works.

Comment: Ohhh, I see it. The `Action` in question is the "invocation" that would be performed by calling the delegate as I do in the lambda- for example, `() => f.BarMethod("foo")` is an `Expression<Action>` with a `Body` whose value is a `MethodCallExpression` calling the *actual* method. Of course the `Action` is never actually called.  It's just used to pass along the method to `ForMethod` in a compile-time-checked way.

Comment: Hi Chris, yes this would work for me if the generic type of my method was static i.e. known at compile time, but i'm getting the method info so that I can construct the generic version of the method dynamically at runtime...(you get a +1 anyway)

Comment: @TimJarvis That much is easy.  Just call `MakeGenericMethod` on the return value of my `ForMethod` function.  My method always returns the Generic Method Definition (the 'template') of the `MethodInfo` if it is generic.  You can pass in any version- `<String>`, `<Int>`, it doesnt matter.  The same thing is returned.

Comment: @ChrisShain, er if I knew that the signature of FooMethod2 was FooMethod2<string> I would not have to make the generic version of it. I could just call it directly. 

:-)

Comment: My point is that *any* version will do.  My method does not return the specific version (e.g. `FooMethod2<String>`).  It returns `FooMethod2<>`, the generic one.  It just uses the `<String>` version as an example to get to the generic one.

Comment: oh yes I see. Still, these methods have between 3 and 5 params and 1 or 2 generic type descriptors....I'd have to dummy up the params and types just to get the method info...ugly. What do you think? worth it just to get runtime checking? or too confusing in the code base.

Comment: Oh I don't think it's worth it at all. Interesting exercise but I think there are better ways to get the root problem accomplished.